# Can I use an XSUB/XPUB zeromq pattern and add a timestamp/sequence number to each message

Tags: c++, proxy, zeromq, publish-subscribe

I am using zeromq to create a generic dynamic graph setup. I already have a XPUB/XSUB setup but am wondering if there is a zmq way of adding a sequence number/timestamp to each message going through generated by the proxy in order to have a uniquely sequenced “tape” of events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Q** : *"... but am wondering if there is a zmq way of adding ... to each message ...?"*

No, there is not. ZeroMQ way would be to have this done with Zero-Copy and <sub>(almost)</sub> Zero-Latency.

Such way does not exist for your wished use-case.

---

### Solution ? Doable :

Create a transforming-node, where each message will get transformed accordingly ( SEQ-number added and TimeSTAMP datum { pre | ap }-pended ). Such step requires one to implement such a node and handle all such steps altogether with any exceptions per incident.

The ready-made API-documented `zmq_proxy()` simply does not and cannot and should not cover these specific requirements, as it was designed for other purposes ( and uses a Zero-Copy for the most efficient pass-through + ev. efficient MITM-logger mode(s) of service ).